# Slider full width on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this slider:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/viBHe

When you open the page the **slider gets the 100% width of the screen**, which is working good and what I want to  achieve but the problem is that when you resize and make the **screen bigger**, then it shows the next slide, like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to keep the `100% width` on resize of the screen?

Also, does anybody knows why is starting from the last slide?

This is the script I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({ height: slideHeight });

  $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, height: slideHeight });

  $('#slider ul li').css({ width: slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 400, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 400, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Comment: Instead of `>` and `<` you should use `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Comment: great, but can you help me with the actual question?

Comment: I dont think using position absolute is the correct way to make a slider.If its ok then i will post a fiddle using proper method of sliders.Should I post it?

Comment: Yeah, post everything you think can help with the question. thank you

Comment: I will post a example fiddle within 20mins

Comment: ok, I can wait for it, thanks

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/hn3dx/ .Hope it helps.Comment if you have any further doubts

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, it helps on the `width:100%` but creates me two new problems, because it doesn't have a timer (it has to be clicked on the arrows to change slide) and also doesn't loop back to the first slide (slide3 to slide1).

Comment: this is the proper way of making sliders **Using an overflowing div** .Timer and loopback can also be done with this

Comment: Yeah I understand (And you are right) but I don't think this slider work for me since like I said, it creates me more problems that the 1 i'm trying to resolve :)

Comment: Also, it still doesn't work with the screen resize. If you resize it you can see the text still floats, not snapping to the left

Comment: Thats also possible to solve.

Comment: Yeah, but can you help me to solve these things? This was the actual question...

Comment: BTW the answer that one of the user posted isnt completely correct.May be that might solve ur problem with ur current slider

Comment: i added an answer.Check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50715/discussion-between-codek-and-zword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try adding px to the answer posted by @SauriolJf

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('li').css({"width":$(window).width()+"px"});
});
```

### [Check CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yCHtm/)

---

I am providing a fiddle created with my way of making a slider , custom made to match the output the asker wants:

### [Slider Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/pjXAQ/)

**HTML**

```
<div>Header</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="slides">Slide1</div>
    <div class="slides">Slide2</div>
    <div class="slides">Slide3</div>
    <div class="slides">Slide4</div>
    <div class="slides">Slide5</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="left"><span>&lt;</span></div>
    <div class="right" style="text-align:right;"><span>&gt;</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,.container,.slides{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0px;
}
.slides{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.buttons{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
}
.left,.right{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:50px;
}
.left span,.right span{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:grey;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var scrolllft=0;
var curSlide=1;

var firstSlide=$('.slides').first().clone(),
lastSlide=$('.slides').last().clone();
$('.container').append(firstSlide);
$('.container').prepend(lastSlide);
var par=$('.container'),
cld=$('.slides');
par.scrollLeft(par.width());
$('.buttons').css('top',par.offset().top+"px");

$('.buttons').on('click','div span',function(){
    if($(this).html() == "&lt;"){
        if(!par.is(':animated')){
            var pr=par.get(0);
            curSlide>0?curSlide--:curSlide=cld.length-3;
            if(curSlide==cld.length-3) par.scrollLeft(pr.scrollWidth-(pr.clientWidth*2));
        par.stop().animate({scrollLeft: par.scrollLeft()-par.width()+"px"}, 750,function(){
            scrolllft = par.scrollLeft()-par.width();
        });
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!par.is(':animated')){
            curSlide<(cld.length-1)?curSlide++:curSlide=2;
            if(curSlide==2) par.scrollLeft(par.width());
         par.stop().animate({scrollLeft: par.scrollLeft()+par.width()+"px"}, 750,function(){
            scrolllft = par.scrollLeft()+par.width();
        });
        }
    }    
});

$(window).resize(function(){
par.scrollLeft(par.scrollLeft()+$('.'+cld.attr('class')+':nth-child('+(curSlide+1)+')').position().left-par.position().left);
});
```

Comment: It works but makes some weird jump at the end of the transition after you resize the screen, can you see it? Also when clicking on the previous arrow it does an strange transition. Can you help me out?

Comment: Ok I will look at it.Which browser r u using?

Comment: Basically there are two problems: 1. When you resize the screen after the page has loaded, the transitions make an strange jump at the end. 2. Clicking on the prev arrow also makes an strange transition.

Comment: @codek I will try to solve it but just I need to ask one question.Will the page contain only slider?If it contains other contents also then position:absolute will cause you too many problems later

Comment: I think it will only contain the slider. I have started a chat with you, can you join it?

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. It works great!! Can you add a setInteval or something like that so it autostarts at load and I also could stop/play it with a `div`. Thank you my friend! I checked the answer.

Comment: Use the else{} part from within `$('.buttons').on('click','div span',function(){ }` in the setInterval function.

Comment: How can I use it? sorry I don't understand for example how to autostart it and how to put that `else` as a function for a `div`

Comment: Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fAuLr/ .I didnt add stop/play .I think you can do that yourself becoz u already have done

Answer (score 0):

For the width of your slider, you could trigger the resize of the window with `.resize()`. Every time window is resize, you readjust the width of the slide.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('div').css({"width":$(window).width()});
});
```

**[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjLkq/)**, resize the window to see that the div will always be 100% of width.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it seems it's not that simple with this slider since it is getting the width for every slide, not just the container.